# How do I import scripts into a service worker using Chrome extension manifest version 3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, browser-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to migrate my chrome extension from manifest version 2 to 3. Now that background scripts are replaced by service workers in manifest v3, I can no longer use a html file and refer `js` files in script tags.

Is there any way I can import my individual script files into the `service_worker.js` file?

I search almost everything on internet and couldn't find any solution. Even the official docs here [Register background scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/background_pages/#manifest) were not so helpful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the built-in importScripts function, see also [Web Workers - How To Import Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45578811)

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm. It worked for me. I tried this yesterday but the service worker failed to start for some reason.

Answer (score 103):

First off, important warnings:

- **Warning: Chrome 92 or older** doesn't show errors occurred in the service worker - it was a [bug](https://crbug.com/1152202), fixed in newer Chrome, which now shows the errors in `chrome://extensions` page. These old versions of Chrome can't register the background script if an unhandled exception occurs during its compilation (a syntax error like an unclosed parenthesis) or initialization (e.g. accessing an undefined variable), so if you still support old Chrome you may want to wrap the code in `try/catch`.
- **Warning: Chrome 92 or older** requires the worker file to be in the root path ([bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66115801/)).
- **Warning!** Don't import DOM-based libraries like **jQuery** or **axios** because service workers don't have DOM so there's no `document`, `XMLHttpRequest`, and so on. Use `fetch` directly or find/write a library that's based on `fetch` and doesn't use `window` or `document`.

## 0. NPM packages

Use a bundler like webpack.

## 1. Static ES modules in Chrome 92 and newer

Enabled by adding `"type": "module"` to the declaration of `background` in manifest.json.

- **Name must start with a path and end with an extension like .js or .mjs**
- Static `import` statement can be used.
- Dynamic `import()` is not yet implemented ([crbug/1198822](https://crbug.com/1198822)).

manifest.json:

```json
"background": { "service_worker": "bg.js", "type": "module" },
"minimum_chrome_version": "92",
```

bg.js:

```js
import {foo} from '/path/file.js';
import './file2.js';
```

As noted at the beginning of this answer, if you still target Chrome 92 or older, which don't surface the errors during registration, each imported module should also use try/catch inside where an exception is possible.

## 2. Global [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts)

This built-in function synchronously fetches and runs the scripts so their global variables and functions become available immediately.

manifest.json:

```json
"background": { "service_worker": "bg-loader.js" },
```

bg-loader.js is just a try/catch wrapper for the actual code in separate files:

```js
try {
  importScripts('/path/file.js', '/path2/file2.js' /*, and so on */);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

If some file throws an error, no subsequent files will be imported. If you want to ignore such errors and continue importing, import this file separately in its own try-catch block.

Don't forget to specify a file extension, typically `.js` or `.mjs`.

## 2b. Dynamic `importScripts` inside a listener

Per the specification, we must use a service worker's `install` event and import all the scripts that we want to be able to import in an asynchronous event later (technically speaking, anything outside of the initial *task* of the *JS event loop*). This handler is called only when the extension is installed or updated or an unpacked extension is reloaded (because it's equal to an update).

It's this convoluted in MV3 because service workers were designed for the Web, where remote scripts may be unavailable offline. Hopefully, it'll be simplified in [crbug/1198822](https://crbug.com/1198822).

See also: [webpack-target-webextension](https://github.com/awesome-webextension/webpack-target-webextension/) plugin for WebPack.

```js
const importedScripts = [];

function tryImport(...fileNames) {
  try {
    const toRun = new Set(fileNames.filter(f => !importedScripts.includes(f)));
    if (toRun.size) {
      importedScripts.push(...toRun);
      importScripts(...toRun);
    }
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

self.oninstall = () => {
  // The imported script shouldn't do anything, but only declare a global function
  // (someComplexScriptAsyncHandler) or use an analog of require() to register a module
  tryImport('/js/some-complex-script.js');
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.action === 'somethingComplex') {
    if (tryImport('/js/some-complex-script.js')) {
      // calling a global function from some-complex-script.js
      someComplexScriptAsyncHandler(msg, sender, sendResponse);
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I get an error " importScripts() of new scripts after service worker installation is not allowed."

Comment: I have some async methods whiting the imported scripts, is this not allowed? @wOxxOm

Comment: see my post https://stackoverflow.com/q/67000104/12550657

Comment: Sadly I get for variant: `2. ES modules in Chrome 92 and newer` error `An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.`. The import is done: `import BuM from './lib/BackupsManager';` and BackupsManager is a default exporting a singleton instance of BackupsManager. Do you have any idea why this might happening @wOxxOm

Comment: By omitting `.js` file extension you're not using the ES module import syntax, which is why it fails.

Comment: @wOxxOm THANK YOU! What a catch xD

Comment: What should I do if I still need to change the DOM in the background js in mv3?

Comment: @mingchau, this is not related to the topic so please ask a new question and describe how you want to use DOM there or show us how you currently do it in your MV2 extension.

Comment: trying ```import { sha256 } from "./web/utils.js";```  fails with ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'``` doesn't work, Inside functions

Comment: I'm getting errors trying to importScripts:
`Error handling response: Error: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'chrome-extension://<extension ID>/scripts/jsencrypt.min.js' failed to load.`
I'm importing it within the listener right before encryption function is called.

Comment: @alcor8, ask a new question with an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm I revised a question that was deemed a duplicate to this one. Could you please help me get it reopened?
[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715942)

Comment: For me jQuery is not working when I add it via background worker script for some reason but when I add another script that will interact with DOM elements I can use it and if I attach anything to window object, I can also access it via content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm does it call scripts in sequence? I want to load `jquery.js` before I use it in `background.js`

Comment: @wOxxOm I just read your message about jQuerym how else can I use it in background?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use chrome-extension-cli

`chrome-extension-cli` package  solves this problem by installing and preconfiguring webpack. This allows you to import packages or modules easily

> #### Get Started Immediately
>
> You **don’t** need to install or configure Webpack.
> Webpack comes in preconfigured, so that you can focus on the code.
>
> Just create a project, and you’re good to go.

Read More: https://github.com/dutiyesh/chrome-extension-cli