# how to import a file in service_worker [chrome extension MV3]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to import a file to keep clean background.js using `manifest_version v3`.

Is't allowed to import, nor am i missing something here ?

```
//manifest.json
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
```

```
//background.js

// error here, cant import a file at all, tried both
import {fetchUsers} from "./xxx/users.js"
const {fetchUsers} = await import(chrome.runtime.getURL('./xxx/users.js'));


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if(request.action == 'fetchUsers'){
    let data = fetchUsers()
    sendResponse({users: data});
  }
});
```

Comment: We can't use ES modules in service workers yet. Use [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) until then.

Comment: @wOxxOm good call, want to submit as an answer? I accept it.

Comment: I'd say [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66408379) already encompasses the topic.

Comment: @wOxxOm Works perfectly, thanks! Please submit as answer :)