# Chrome extension's service worker stops listening for events when the popup is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, service-worker, manifest

I'm trying to get the extension to listen for tab updates, take the URL, send that to the popup, then have the popup send the URL to my server. When the popup is open, everything works exactly as I expect it to. When I close the popup, however, the service worker stops listening for tab updates, so everything stops working. It seems like this would have been really easy to do with Manifest V2 with persistent backgrounds, but service workers don't seem to do that?

Here's the code:

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if (changeInfo.url){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage({
            msg: changeInfo.url
        })
    }
})
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log("From popup.js")
    console.log(request.msg)
    $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", function(data) {
        const ip = (data.ip)
        const sid = socket.id
        socket.emit('new url', request.msg, ip, sid)
    })
})
```

Again, this all works perfectly as long as the popup is open, but when the popup is closed, the background script stops listening and firing. Manifest.JSON includes 'tabs' in permissions, not sure if I maybe need something else.

--EDIT-- Showing some more code:

popup.js

```
var socket = io.connect('http://my_ip_address');

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log("From popup.js")
    console.log(request.msg)
    $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", function(data) {
        const ip = (data.ip)
        const sid = socket.id
        socket.emit('new url', request.msg, ip, sid)
    })
})
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if (changeInfo.url){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            msg: changeInfo.url
        })
    }
})
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, json, Response, render_template, session
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

@socketio.on('new url')
def handle_new_url(url, ip, sid, methods=["GET"]):
    print("attempting to print url")
```

Assuming that the fix is that I need to bypass popup.js and to instead have background.js speak directly to app.py, then the solution seems to be to just socket.emit from the background straight to the server. However, this doesn't work because background.js doesn't know what sockets are -- popup.js can use socketio because I have it imported in popup.html.

EDIT 2

new background.js:

```
var socketscript = document.createElement('script')
socketscript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js')
document.head.appendChild(socketscript)

var socket = io.connect('my_ip_address');

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if (changeInfo.url){
        socket.emit('new url', changeInfo.url, 1, 2)
    }
})
```

Comment: The popup is a separate window. It runs only when it's open.

Comment: In other words, I need to pass the URL information directly from the background to the server without going through the popup?

Comment: Probably. I can't help without a new [MCVE](/help/mcve) that shows more of the logic.

Comment: edited OP with a bit more detail.

Comment: So yes, move `io` and onMessage listener in the background script and use `fetch` instead of jQuery as it won't work in service worker.

Comment: I tried putting ```io``` in background.js but I get the "Service Worker registration failed" error message. I tried importing socketio but that didn't work either.

edit: oops guess you can't put formatted code in comments, i'll edit OP again

Comment: Service workers don't have DOM so you can't use `document`. You need to download the script and import it locally, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66408379).

Comment: That works! Brings up a few other issues that I need to solve, but this is definitely a step in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Okay these issues are harder to solve than I thought... if I try to import the socketio cdn, I get errors re: CSP that don't seem fixable. If I try to download the cdn and import it as a local js file, I get weird errors about documents not being defined (which is bizarre because popup.html is able to use the downloaded socketio script without issue). Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like this library wants to use DOM so it's not compatible with service workers.

Comment: That seems like a hell of a hurdle to get around. So is there any simple/go-to method for sending a regular post request from a service worker? XMLHttpRequests seem to break things too, as does jquery, so I'm at a loss for how else to do it.

Comment: You can use `fetch`.