# importScripts while error thrown from one of the script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, import

In my chrome extension (manifest V3) I want to import some scripts like jquery and more.

Inside my backgound.js I have:

```
try {
    importScripts('/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', '/js/common.js');
} catch (e) {
    console.error('importScripts: ' + e);
}
...
calling to getCookie...
```

inside `common.js` I have function like:

```
async function getCookie(key) {   
    return ...;
}
```

but when I load the extension I get the error:

> background.js:22 importScripts: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined

This error comes from the Jquery library

and after I get another error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined

because the error in jquery it doesn't load the common script? how can I fix that?

Is there a more stable solution to import the scripts? so that error in one script will not cause a fail to other scripts?

Comment: The problem is that jQuery can't be used in a service worker because jQuery is DOM-based but service workers don't have neither DOM nor related things like XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I'm getting `XMLHttpRequest is not defined` @wOxxOm

Comment: This is exactly what my comment says.

Comment: To rephrase, don't use jQuery.

Comment: @wOxxOm Then how can I preform an http call within the background script

Comment: You can use `fetch`.

Comment: @wOxxOm till now in V2 all my http request was with ajax in background script, so now I should replace all to fetch? that's insane

Comment: Yes, half the changes in ManifestV3 are insane but it is what it is.

Answer (score 4):

Posting the working solution for me: **import the scripts from npm into background service worker:**

1. In my **manifest.json** adding `"type": "module"` to my background script:

```
"background": {"service_worker": "background.js" , "type":"module"}
```

2. Inside my **background.js** simply importing desired module script:

```
import Dexie from "/node_modules/dexie/dist/modern/dexie.min.mjs"
```

**REMAKRS:**

- Please  notice that from **Manifest Version 3** in order to invoke script into web-page from your **background service workers** you need to use `chrome.scripting.executeScript`.  **Example**:

```js
//background.js
let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})

      //invoke function
      await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        function: colorSelectedText,
        args: [tab.title]
      })
  });
//OR
      //invoke file
      await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        files: ['your_script.js']
      })
  });
```

- Desirable scripts must be in same parent folder as your manifest.json (wasn't working when I was trying to use two dots `../path`)

Answer (score 1):

You can package your extension application with the version of jquery you would like to use . then you add it as part of your service workers.    This is how my manifest.json looks like

```
    {
    "name": "Foo Bar",
  "description": "NA",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
],
"action": {
    
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": { "service_workers": ["bg-loader.js","/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" ]}

}
```

I have a bg-loader.js which i use to import my js logic script where i have my jquery functions

```
try {
    importScripts('/js/index.js' /*, and so on */);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Then in my index.html i add my jquery script to my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
 


</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if the code will work, but using manifest V3, changing service_worker to service_workers in manifest.json, causes Chrome to not enable the "Inspect views/service worker" link in the extension details, making it much more difficult to debug the extension.