# Access DOM from background in Chrome extension v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I relate to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406672/chrome-extension-mv3-modularize-service-worker-js-file/66408379#66408379) from [@woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom): particularly to this warning:

> Warning! Don't import DOM-based libraries like jQuery because service
> workers don't have DOM so there's no document, XMLHttpRequest, and so
> on.

How to use and access DOM with XMLHttpRequest in v3 context?

Comment: There's no API for this in MV3, https://crbug.com/1056354. You can import a library like JSDOM but it's 5MB minified. You can find a smaller library but they don't implement full DOM API.

Comment: I'm looking for possibility to make XHR request, and get as response  a content from special HTML element, addressed with XPath. Do you probably know a small library for this ? About the bug report: how do you see chances it will be fixed before v3 becomes mandatory?

Comment: 1) I don't know. 2) Judging by the fact that they already disabled submission of new MV2 extensions in the web store, Google doesn't think this is important, so it's quite possible they won't fix it before removing MV2. There are too many such problems in MV3 for the current development team to handle in time.