# Azure Cognitive Services sdk implementation in chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, es6-modules, azure-cognitive-services, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm having a trouble with the migration from the MV2 to MV3 in my chrome extension application.
With the MV2, everything worked fine implementing the azure library in the **background.js** file through the html one.
But with the MV3 and the **background.js** file becoming a service worker i tried several thing to make my app functional with no results.

According to the documentation, i switched background part in the manifest file to :

```
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
```

I built the module of the azure cognitive services sdk through https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js

But when i try to import it in the background.js like this :

```
import * as SpeechSDK from './distrib/es2015/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.js';
var speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
  "key",
  "region"
);
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "fr-FR";
speechConfig.outputFormat = SpeechSDK.OutputFormat.Detailed;
```

I get the error "**Service worker registration failed**" and "**An unknown error occurred when fetching the script**."
I tried multiples things like using a wrapper or the importScripts function according to this post : [chrome extension mv3 - Modularize service worker js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406672/chrome-extension-mv3-modularize-service-worker-js-file#answer-66408379) but none of them worked for me.
Do you have any idea how to use the azure cognitive services in a chrome extension MV3 ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Service workers don't have the necessary API for audio/speech. Welcome to ManifestV3 that breaks thousands of extensions. You'll have to open a new tab/window and do the processing there or add an [extension iframe](/a/25100953) inside the web page.

Comment: Oh yeah didn't thought the problem could be that. So i guess AudioContext() and co doesn't work anymore in service worker. Not very cool.. As you said maybe the best thing to do is to avoid this weird backgroud file. I will try what you suggested. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1. **Hot Permission:**

In MV3 you need to mention the hot permissions separately. Follow the below code block to mention the hot permissions.

```
// Manifest V3
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks"
],
"optional_permissions": [
  "unlimitedStorage"
],
"host_permissions": [
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
  "*://*/*"
],
```

2. **CSP (Content Security Policy):**

Check the CSP headers code block.

```
// Manifest V3

"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages": "...",
  "sandbox": "..."
}
```

3. **Action API Unification:**

There is a small different between MV2 and MV3 implementation in ***background.js***

```
// Manifest V3

// manifest.json
{
  "action": { … }
}


// background.js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => { … });
```

For better reference, check out the below document.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/