# Chrome extension: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

There are a bunch of similar threads on here however I cannot seem to find anything that works for me. I am building a chrome extension where I'd like to connect to a websocket. I have found a project, https://github.com/matthewlawson/lnm-socket.io, which I try to use as inspiration although I cannot make it work for me.

The server is not in the chrome extension, however I try to access it from my background.js file. That's when I get the *Cannot use import statement outside a module* error message. Adding "type": "module" to my package.json file doesn't seem to fix it and since it is the background file I do not have it in a script tag to place the "type": "module" in. What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome extension mv3 - Modularize service worker js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406672/chrome-extension-mv3-modularize-service-worker-js-file) - add `"type": "module"` to the `background` section in manifest.json.

Comment: Adding it to the manifest.json surely did something, however, I still cannot "import io from 'socket.io-client'; " since it doesn't start with a /

I find this peculiar since it works in this 5 year old project. I guess it might have to do with the new version not supporting it yet, but I am here to ask - is there a way for me to do this that I am not aware of?

Comment: You can't use DOM-based libraries in a service worker. Find a compatible one.

Comment: Any suggestions? Feels like I've searched the whole internet to find a server - client solution to chrome extensions that are not deprecated...

Comment: @wOxxOm how can I do with a contentscript?

Comment: [How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033388)