# Invalid value for 'background.service_worker'. Could not load manifest

Tags: manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

I am trying to migrate/update a manifest 2 file to manifest 3. But I am getting the following error  `Invalid value for 'background.service_worker'. Could not load manifest.`

From the original maifest 2 file I removed `"persistent": true` and changed `"background": {"scripts": ["background.js", "worker.js"],` to be `"background": {"service_worker":["background.js", "worker.js"],`

My full code for v3 can be seen below:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 3,

"name": "Chrome ext",
"description": "This is an extension ",
 "version": "1.1.1",
 "icons": {
"128":"icon.png"
  },

 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_title": "Open ext"
 },
 "options_page": "options.html",
 "background": {
"service_worker": ["background.js", "worker.js"]

},
"permissions": [
  "tabCapture",
  "downloads",
 "storage"
 ],
 "commands": {
  "start": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "default": "Ctrl+Shift+S",
    "mac": "Command+Shift+U"
  },
  "description": "Start"
},
"stop": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "default": "Ctrl+Shift+X",
    "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+X"
  },
  "description": "Stop"
}
```

}
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome extension mv3 - Modularize service worker js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406672/chrome-extension-mv3-modularize-service-worker-js-file)

Comment: It must be a string not an array. You will load the additional scripts inside, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66408379).

Answer (score 2):

You might need to follow below syntax

```
"background": {
     "service_worker": "background.js"
 }
```

and import both the scripts in single file