# Import module in Chrome Extension Service Worker with Vite and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, vite

I'm working on a Chrome extension using Vite and React. The goal is to have it work along with my web application, and share a Supabase authentication session between the two. I'm having trouble importing the `supabase-js` library in my background script.

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "Supabase Chrome Extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "author": "cpppatrick",
  "icons": {
    "16": "extension_icon16.png",
    "32": "extension_icon32.png",
    "48": "extension_icon48.png",
    "128": "extension_icon128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open extension"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1:5173/*", "https://127.0.0.1:5173/*"]
  }
}
```

Here is my `vite.config.js` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['@supabase/supabase-js'],
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        index: './index.html',
        background: fileURLToPath(new URL('./public/background.js', import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
    // I have tried building with & without this key.
    commonjsOptions: {
       include: [/node_modules/],
     },
  },
  define: {
    'process.env': {},
  },
});
```

And finally here is my `background.js` file:

```js
import { createClient } from '../node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js';

const options = {
  auth: {
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: true,
    storage: {
      async getItem(key) {
        const storage = await chrome.storage.local.get(key);
        return storage?.[key];
      },
      async setItem(key, value) {
        await chrome.storage.local.set({
          [key]: JSON.parse(value),
        });
      },
      async removeItem(key) {
        await chrome.storage.local.remove(key);
      },
    },
  },
};

export const supabase = createClient(
  import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL,
  import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
  options
);
```

I believe it is a problem with the `import` statement because when I comment it out and run `npm run build`, everything builds and I don't receive any errors.

The files in this state produce the following errors, which are giving me trouble:

[image]

What I have tried so far:

- Tried using `crxjs/vite-plugin` as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264854/5046696). But it doesn't work with Vite 4 yet.
- The `importScripts` approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66408379/5046696). That gave me different errors.
- Various tweaks to my `vite.config.js` file.

I don't have a lot of experience with Rollup, so I'm getting turned around trying to work with the options in my `vite.config.js` file. And the error messages are not giving me a lot to work with.

TL;DR:

- How can I get imports working in my `background.js` file?

Comment: Apparently supabase is not compatible with service worker. Either find a compatible version or use it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).

Comment: Try to change the import using `importScripts` instead of ES `import`. I'm not sure about Chrome extensions but by default, Service Workers don't support ES Modules. You need to specifically set it as a module. https://web.dev/es-modules-in-sw/

Comment: @wOxxOm If I create an offscreen document, do I put that logic in `background.js`? And do I need to add an entry point for the page in my `vite.config.js`, since the docs say it needs to be a static HTML file?

Comment: The offscreen document is a separate entry. You can use messaging via `chrome.runtime` or `navigator.serviceWorker` to communicate.