# Global Constants in background_worker.js and popup.js - Chrome Extention v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, constants

I really want to share constants with all my js files, background_serviceworker.js and popup.js.

```
const EXTENSION_MODE = {
    SEARCH_ONLY: "searchOnly",
    FILTER: "filter",
    OFF: "off"
}
```

Just putting vars in the background_serviceworker.js and using getBackgroundPage() seems a bit messy to me (can make the background file very big).

Answer (score 1):

I created constants.js.

```
// constants.js
var EXTENSION_MODE = Object.freeze({
    SEARCH_ONLY: "searchOnly",
    FILTER: "filter",
    OFF: "off"
})
```

Inject it to the background-service-worker file (using an answer from here [Service worker registration failed. Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114920/service-worker-registration-failed-chrome-extension) to actually see the errors from the injected script. Without, you only see very general error)

```
// background.js
try { importScripts("constants.js"); } catch (e) { console.error(e); }
```

Now popup.js still don't have access to that, because it runs in isolated contexed.
So I Also injected it to the popup.html (In the good old fashion way).

```
 <!-- popup.html -->
<body>
    <some-other-elements/>
    <script src="./constants.js"></script>
    <script src="./popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

And I can use it in popup.js

```
// popup.js
console.log("popup: " + EXTENSION_MODE.FILTER);
```

PS. on content scripts (injected using the chrome.scripting.executeScript), we won't use it. There we need to start using Storage and Messaging https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/