# How to import js file to background.js in chrome extension from the same folder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, requirejs, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm having a problem importing the file "score.js" that is in same library of the "background.js" (scripts libary).
I'm new to both js and chrome extensions.
I looked into require.js and did this.

Background.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tab Manager</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Tab Manager</h1>
    <script data-main="scripts/score.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

background.js:

```
// gets a dictionary of existing windows ids as keys and tab arrays as values.
function get_windows() 
{
    var window_dict = {};
    chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true}, windowArr =>{
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < windowArr.length; i++) {
            var window = windowArr[i];
            var window_id = window.id;
            var tabs = window.tabs;
            window_dict[window_id] = tabs;
          }
        console.log(window_dict);
        main(window_dict);
    })
    
}

function starting_scores(window_dict)
{
    var scores = [];
    var i;
    var j = 0;
    var total_tabs = [];
    for (const [window_id, tabs] of Object.entries(window_dict)) {
        for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
            scores[j] = new Score(tabs[i], window_id);
            j = j++;
        }}
    return scores;
}

function main(window_dict)
{
    var scores = starting_scores(window_dict);
    console.log(scores);
}

get_windows();
```

score.js:

```
class Score
{   
    // Constructor
    constructor(tab, window_id)
        {
        this.window_id = window_id; // The window id of the window that contains the tab.
        this.tab = tab; 
        this.url = tab.url;
        this.active = tab.active; // If the tab is currently looked at then it's active.
        this.audible = tab.audible; // If the tab is playing audio then audible will be true.
        this.discarded = tab.discarded; // If the tab is already unloaded but not closed this will be true.

        /* If the new tab is active then the timer is set to zero because 
        the user hasn't spent any time not using the tab. Otherwise a timer starts. */
        if(this.active == true){
            this.timer == 0;}
        else{
            this.timer = performance.now;}
        }
    
    // Get methods
    getWindowId() {
        return this.window_id;
    }
    getTab() {
        return this.tab;
    }
    getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }
    getActive() {
        return this.active;
    }
    getAudible() {
        return this.audible;
    }
    getDiscarded() {
        return this.discarded;
    }
    getTimer() {
        return this.timer;
    }

    // Set methods
    setWindowId(window_id) {
        this.window_id = window_id;
    }
    setTab(tab) {
        this.tab = tab;
    }
    setUrl(url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    setActive(active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    setAudible(audible) {
        this.audible = audible;
    }
    setDiscarded(discarded) {
        this.discarded = discarded;
    }
    setTimer(timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build an extension that makes a score for usage for each tab and then removes the ones with low score. Don't mind the logic I just can't get score.js to work in background.js

Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 23):

An update to [@wOxxOm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67513850/2463800), starting with Manifest v3, you cannot use `background.page`, but you can load the script as a module directly.

**manifest.json**

```json
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
}
```

**background.js**

```js
import Score from './score.js';
```

**score.js**

```js
export default class Score
```

Comment: now it is showing `Service worker registration failed`

Comment: Looks like that happens if the background script throws an error during installation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66115801/2463800

Comment: @TrevinAvery what about `content.js` file? Can I import functions in it?

Comment: I don't know what `content.js` is, but you can probably load it as a module, either through the background as shown above or through a script tag as shown in @wOxxOm's answer. If you do, anything you export will be accessible. So simply export the functions you want.

Comment: If someone is stuck on `Service worker registration failed` since last =one hour, the solution is to do `import Score from './score.js';` and not `import Score from './score';`. Just putting it out here .

Comment: Adding `"type": "module"` absolutely, 100% does not work at all. Not even a little bit.

`import Score from './score.js';` instead of `import Score from './score';` also does not work at all.

Answer (score 7):

### ManifestV3

There are several methods:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66408379

#### ManifestV2

Remove require.js and use the built-in ES modules import.

**manifest.json**:

```json
"background": {
  "page": "background.html"
}
```

**background.html**, the entire file is just one line:

```html
<script src="background.js" type="module"></script>
```

**background.js**, insert at the beginning of the file:

```js
import Score from './score.js';
```

**The imported script** score.js, change the first line:

```
export default class Score
```

**Remember** that if you don't use a bundler/compiler like WebPack the file name in `import` must include the path (`./` means "same directory") and the file extension, otherwise it won't work. A typical file extension for a module is `.mjs`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was having so much trouble importing files I thought js was just not for me. This is actually for a school project I'm doing and it's due soon. This helped me a ton and enabled me to keep coding.

Comment: (manifest V3) I get this Extension Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: @Alex75, this answer is for ManifestV2. See [chrome extension mv3 - Modularize service worker js file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66408379)