# Browser Extension Manifest v3 with webextension-polyfill does not allow browser.browserAction.onClicked (on Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions, browser-extension, webextension-polyfill

I am building a browser extension. I want to trigger a notification when the user clicks on the extension's icon. When I try to load the extension in Chrome, I get this error: **Service worker registration failed**

[image]

As the source of the error, it highlights "background.js" in the manifest (which you find further down). No further information is given. However, the problem only occurs if I have the first snippet in background.ts, as indicated by the comments:

```js
import { browser } from "webextension-polyfill-ts";

// This code prevents the compiled extension to be loaded into Chrome
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  console.log('browserAction.onClicked');
});

// I also have this code in the file, which works just fine.
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(() => {
  console.log('browser.runtime.onMessage');
});
```

(Note that this is of course compiled into Javascript)

Of course I suspected a permissions issue, but could not find anything suspicious. Here is the complete manifest:

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
 "action": {
    "default_title": "Click to show an alert"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/content-script.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {}
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any error messages when you click on `Inspect views background page` in the chrome extension menu.

Comment: 1) There's no `browserAction` in MV3, it uses a combined `action` API, see the migration guide. 2) MV3 uses Promise for most of its API and more are coming so you shouldn't need the polyfill.

Comment: Wait it does? I spent so much effort getting webextension-polyfill to work with MV3 because I thought I was stuck with the callback-based API, even using webpack and stuff...

Comment: @lejlun - I cannot inspect the background page, as the extension does not load in the first place. :-(

Comment: @wOxxOm - Are you referring to the Chrome migration guide? But that's chrome-specific (chrome.action.onClicked...) How do I write this browser-agnostic? That's why I tried to use polyfill.

Comment: Well, don't use the polyfill as it's almost completely useless for MV3. To debug the error, see [Service worker registration failed. Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66114920)

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your manifest under background key

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
    "type": "module"

  }
```