# How to register a service worker of in chrome extension - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am trying to access run some background script in an chrome extension build using react how can I register a service worker to do so?

Comment: There's no need to register it. Just declare it in manifest.json as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service worker registration failed. Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114920/service-worker-registration-failed-chrome-extension)